# Identify first login and last logout entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that needs to determine the first time a user logged in to the system and the last time the user logged out.

The login and logout report comes from another system from which I copy and paste the data to my spreadsheet. This report is not sorted in chronological order.

Basically, since the users use the system to login and logout, they will have multiple records of logging in and out on a daily basis. I need to find the very first login record and last logout record per user.

I tried to use `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` to do this, but I could only return the very first entry for each user. Like I mentioned earlier the extracted report is not sorted in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires the use of two array formulas:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `F2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the table column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$B$2:$B$15,MAX($B$2:$B$15)))}
```

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `G2` and copy-paste/fill-down into the rest of the table column (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$C$2:$C$15,MIN($C$2:$C$15)))}
```

Both these formulas work by generating an array of the relevant times when a row matches the appropriate user, and a special value when it doesn't. The trick is to choose a special value such that it doesn't interfere with the `=MIN(…)` and `=MAX(…)` functions used to extract the First Login and Last Logout.

These special values are the maximum of all the login times for the `MIN` case, and the minimum of all the logout times for the `MAX` case.

---

Of course, you could just use any arbitrarily large number for the `MIN` case

```dart
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$B$2:$B$15,10^9))}
```

and zero for the `MAX` case

```dart
{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$C$2:$C$15,0))}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If any of the data in the report (`User`, `Login`, or `Logout`) can by missing, then the formulas need to be adapted. It is simplest to modify the last two formulas above.

The `F2` formula becomes

```dart
{=IFERROR(1/(1/(1/(1/MIN(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$B$2:$B$15,10^9)))-1/(1/10^9)))+10^9,"")}
```

and the `G2` formula changes to

```dart
{=IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(IF($A$2:$A$15=$E2,$C$2:$C$15,0))),"")}
```

To understand how these modifications work, it's best to start with the second formula.

The `1/(1/MAX(…))` converts a zero result to a `#DIV/0!` error, but leaves all other values alone<sup>*</sup>. A zero result occurs if either there are no login times for a specified user, or there are no records at all for that user.

The `IFERROR()` then converts the error into a blank. (Note that you could substitute any string for the blank, if so desired.)

The first formula is a little bit more complicated as when there exist no matching records, a result of `10^9` is returned instead of a zero. (A zero is still returned for the case of no logout times, though.)

So, a `10^9` conversion to a blank is required as well as a zero conversion. This second conversion is done by subtracting `10^9` from the first zero-to-error conversion result, and converting this to an error if it's a zero. The initial result is then restored by adding a `10^9`. Of course, if the partial result was an error, the error is retained.

The `-1/(1/10^9)` instead of a `-10^9`is required to account for floating point errors.

The `IFERROR()` then converts the error into a blank just like it did in the second formula.

Comment: It's still capturing someone else's login and logout times even if the user either: 1) is not logged in 2) has no login time but has a recorded logout time 3) has login time but has no recorded logout time

Comment: @Astrid22 Ah, well, you didn't specify that there could be missing times/users. I'll have to adjust the formulas. They'll be a little more complicated. EDIT: All done. The answer has been updated with the new formulas.

Comment: I have a follow up question, though. The users' schedule is night to morning (example, July 1 8PM to July 2 5AM then the same for the next day). I noticed that for the next day, it's capturing the lowest recorded login time of the same day instead of the first login the user did for the next day's shift. This doesn't happen to schedules that start and end on the same day @robinCTS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80277/discussion-between-robincts-and-astrid-22).